Regex to match lines followed by another Line
I'm working with a text input and i need a regex pattern to capture lines that are followed by another line. Specifically i want to match lines that end with exactly one newline character and are immediately followed by another line (Except Last Line)
Here is an example of my input:
DontCapture

capture this line
capture this line
capture this line

DontCaptureDontCapture

DontCaptureDontCapture

this is my pattern:
^[^\n\r]*(?=\n(?!\n))
the problem with this it captures the lines but it ignore the last line:
https://regex101.com/r/kHiwm0/1

You might match the whole paragraphs with ^.+(?:\n.+)+. Then you can split with \n to get the lines separately.

You could also use something like (?m)^.++(?=\n\S)|^(?<=\S\n).+ (PCRE/PHP)

You could do a look behind, something like this.
^((?:[^\n\r]*(?=\n(?!\n)))|(?:(?<=\w[\n\r])[^\n\r]+))

